# Strange error debugging entity framework repository methods: data persisted even after abort

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, objectcontext

I'm having a strange error debugging my ASP.NET MVC 4 project running on Entity Framework 5. I used the model first approach. I'm calling a simple update method called from an AJAX Grid when data is updated. The issue is that changes are persisted to the database even if I set a break-point and abort debugging before the update is done.

I use an `ObjectContext` to actually save changes to the db:

```
var updates = context.SaveChanges();
```

The above line is called by a Save() defined on a repository class:

```
public static bool Save(UserModel currentUser, BulletinModel model)
{
    if (model == null) return false;

    if (model.Id > 0)
        Update(currentUser, model);
    else 
        // more code goes here ...
```

I set a break-point on the first line in the `Save()` method above to inspect data to be updated. However, if I click "stop debugging" at this point, where the update method has not been called yet, the changes are still persisted to my sql server database.

Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

When you are debugging a Web Application in Visual Studio, the "Stop Debugging" button does not mean that your application process is stopped completely. Instead, it just detach the debugging process and the rest of the code continues to run (you might see the IIS Express process or IIS Server is still running after you stop debugging). To ultimately stop it, use 'Debug' -> 'Terminate All'.